# Java compilation error for custom kerberos filter class

Tags: java

I am compiling some old java code for kerberosfilter. I am getting below error.

Can you please help.

Here is the snippet of the code.

```
@Override
public Enumeration<?> getHeaderNames() {
  Vector<Object> headers = new Vector<Object>();
  HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)this.getRequest();
  for (Enumeration<?> e = req.getHeaderNames() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
    headers.add(e.nextElement());
  }
  headers.add("KRB_USER");
  return headers.elements();
}
```

**Error message.**

> KerberosSSOFilter.java:324: error: getHeaderNames() in
> KerberosSSOFilter.KerberosAuthWrapper cannot implement
> getHeaderNames() in HttpServletRequest
> public Enumeration getHeaderNames() {
> ^   return type Enumeration is not compatible with Enumeration

Comment: Perhaps they are referencing different Enumeration classes?

Comment: Does the method you're overriding have it declared exactly like that?  Also, you're returning Vector<Object> so maybe it is applying that to your return type.  ??  (I don't think so, but try declaring headers as exactly the type you're returning.)

Comment: Oh.  I'll bet that what you entered as the error message is not what I'm seeing, because HTML is eating the &gt; and &lt; signs.  Is there something after the word Enumeration?